# Using Dedekind's prime ideal factorisation theorem

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I've been going over past papers for algebraic number theory and came across this question which has given me some trouble:

Given a number field $K =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ where $ d\equiv 1 \mod 4$ is a square-free integer. If $p$ is a prime divisor of $d$, what does Dedekind's theorem on the decomposition of a rational prime $p$ into prime ideals tell you about the factorization of $p$ over $K$?

I've had ideas about proving irreducibility/reducibility using the fact that d is square-free but nothing's really working.

Answer (score 1):

The results are the following, for an odd prime:

- $p$ is *inert* (i.e; remains irreducible) if the discriminant $-4d$ is *not* a square modulo $p$.
- $p$ *splits* as the product of two prime ideals (with norm $p$) if $-4d$ is a non-zero square modulo $p$.
- $p$ is *ramified* (is the square of a prime ideal with norm $p$) if $-4d\equiv 0\mod p$

Comment: What Dedekind's theorem says about the ideal factorization is clear; I got the impression that the question wanted me to comment on the factorization of the element $p$.